# Show asp.net UpdateProgress control on submit only

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have a page with 2 buttons on.

I want to show the updateprogress only when the page is submitted via one of the buttons, but not the other cancel button. I've been struggling for a while to come up with a solution.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter `AssociatedUpdatePanelID` for `UpdateProgress`, and set `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for UpdatePanel to button you want to make a postback.

If above instructions doesn't help, you can also try to wrap controls you need into `asp:Panel` control and set `DefaultButton` to your Submit button ID.

Comment: The problem is that both buttons update the page. So the content is with an update panel that contains both buttons.